# Microphone not working at all after fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: microphone

My headset microphone doesn't work at all after installing ubuntu 18.04.3. It is enabled in settings, but doesn't pick up my voice while recording. When I turn it up, the recording noise is turned up as well, but no voice is recorded. What can I do to make the mic work? The very same mic works well in Manjaro.